# Is there a word to describe the feeling of wanting to be someone else

Tags: meaning

Is there a word that describes having a deep desire to have a different life ( because the current life is bad), or a word that describes a longing to forget the past or just forget everything in general?

Comment: Let's not forget plain old "envy".

Comment: I think the title and the description are asking for 2 different things.

Comment: Consider also *vicarious*: "experienced in the imagination through the feelings or actions of another person" You might wish to *live vicariously* through another specific person by learning all about that person's life.

Comment: I think it makes a difference whether the person concerned wants to be someone else *specific* or just to be someone other than who they actually are.

Comment: I just want to say that whoever is reading this is probably doing the same thing I was and if you think that your not good enough and you want to be someone else just know that your amazing and you are loved <3

Answer (score 9):

I think escapism would do for me. Becoming more popular too these days.

Answer (score 4):

One possibility is [*dysphoria:*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/dysphoria)

> **NOUN**
>
> *Psychiatry*
>
> A state of unease or generalized dissatisfaction with life. The opposite of euphoria.
>
> EXAMPLE SENTENCES
>
> *Post has suggested a clinical continuum of euphoria, dysphoria and paranoid psychosis that occurs with regular cocaine use that is related to dosage, genetics and previous exposure.*
>
> *Researchers found that sociotropy and negative affect were nonspecifically and positively correlated with both dysphoria and anxiety in 485 undergraduates.*
>
> *There is, in fact, evidence that benzodiazepines are of greater benefit when used to treat either patients with moderate to high levels of anxiety or dysphoria.*
>
> **Origin**
>
> mid 19th century: from Greek *dusphoria*, from *dusphoros* 'hard to bear'.
>
> **Derivatives**
>
> dysphoric
>
> Pronunciation: /-ˈfôrik/
>
> **ADJECTIVE & NOUN**
>
> EXAMPLE SENTENCES
>
> *In addition to a general level of irritability, children with mania also present with extremely impairing dysphoric, explosive episodes that generally occur daily with little or no precipitant.*
>
> *‘The implication for treatment is that if you ask dysphoric people to recall nice events from their lives it may not make them feel any better,’ Joormann notes.*
>
> *Although the average depression lasts around six months, those with severe major depression or constant dysphoric depression may have symptoms that last for years.*

(Definition and examples from Oxforddictionaries.com)

Answer (score 0):

*Be in somebody's shoes* is an idiomatic expression of what you'd like to say.

As [Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/step-into-someone%27s-shoes) say, it means to put yourself in someone's situation.

> If I’d been in your shoes I’d have walked out on him.

(Definition and the example from Oxforddictionaries.com)

Answer (score 0):

- *fantasizing, daydreaming*
- *identity crisis*
- *(feeling of) inadequacy*
- *unfulfilled*
- possibly also: *impostor syndrome*, *wanderlust*, ...

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the cause, that could be [**ennui**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/ennui):

> A feeling of listlessness and dissatisfaction arising from a lack of occupation or excitement
>
> - *The physical environment itself is a crucial factor in the creation of unhappiness, ennui, anger, alienation and despair.*
> - *He is portraying an English landscape of barren trees, a place of despair, ennui and fear.*
> - *But for those who are privileged to get their life extended forever, will boredom and ennui not set in?*

Answer (score 0):

*Metamorphosis* is  suitable  in the  context.

> He wants  to  metamorphosize  himself  into  somebody  else.

Here  are  the  links

https://www.yourdictionary.com/metamorphosize

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/metamorphosis

Answer (score 0):

**Wistful**

Wistful is ‘having or showing a feeling of vague or regretful longing‘. It is hankering after what was; pensive, melancholy.

Example:

- Diana gazed wistfully at the departing figure of Jack, longing for what might have been.
- Freda gave a wistful smile “I would so have loved to have spent more time at the beach instead of working”, she said.

https://www.dictionary.com/browse/wistful

Answer (score -2):

A word for me word for me would be "Nostalgia"
a sentimental longing or wistful affection for a period in the past.
"I was overcome with acute nostalgia for my days at university"
synonyms:   wistfulness, longing/yearning/pining for the past, regret, regretfulness, reminiscence, remembrance, recollection, homesickness, sentimentality
"there is a nostalgia for traditional values"
something done or presented in order to evoke feelings of nostalgia.
"an evening of TV nostalgia

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage, a question and answer site for linguists, etymologists, and serious English language enthusiasts.This site strives to provide objective answers. Take the [site tour](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour) or have a look at the [help center](https://english.stackexchange.com/help) to find out more about good answers. As it stands your answer is purely subjective.

Comment: Also, you might want to take a closer look at the question: "... a longing to **forget** the past ..."