# a word for wanting to be somewhere else

Tags: single-word-requests

In German, the word *Fernweh* translates roughly as "farsickness." It denotes the desire to be somewhere other than where you are now. It was coined as an antonym to *Heimweh*, or "homesickness."

Does English have a good word to indicate the feeling of wanting to be somewhere else?

Comment: Related:http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/212474/is-there-a-word-to-describe-the-feeling-of-wanting-to-be-someone-else

Comment: @Josh61: not really about wanting a different life or forgetting about the past, as that question asks, but as in: here I am at my desk working (and I love my work), but right now I wish I were on the dock at Manhattan Beach.

Comment: Two related concepts are *cabin fever* - when we're stuck indoors someplace for extended periods of time and just want to get out, and *daydreaming*, when we fantasize about being somewhere else.

Comment: Isn't it Longing.

Comment: There is the same question in [german.stackexchange](http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/76/how-to-translate-fernweh-to-english). They suggested "itchy feet" there.

Comment: In my opinion, _farsickness_, as a neologism, is the best word. The problem might be that it is not common (yet).

Comment: @ermanen How common does it have to be to become a word (neologisms are words by all definitions)?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: I didn't say that it is not a word, in fact i said it is the "best word". So what is the question for?

Comment: You said it is a word. I don't accept people saying '..... is a word' without support from say an accepted dictionary, evidence that it is part of the lexicon. The few examples I can find for 'farsickness' are transliterations.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: Sorry, your question sounded like the opposite.  "Farsickness" is a neologism and neologisms are words also. There are few sources that it is not mentioned as a transliteration but even it is the case, it is used as a _word_. Also, "fernweh" is a neologism too but gained usage in German. I think "farsickness" didn't gain enough usage so people might not think that it is a word. "What makes a word a word" was discussed in another question also, there was a comprehensive answer but I couldn't find.

Comment: @ermanem At a railway theme park over 20 years ago, I partly informed, partly warned my little son about a locomotive just a few metres away: 'That's a _steam_ locomotive'. It blew off water from its cylinders a second later. My son and I both jumped. Then he said, '_Very_ steam , that one.' He used 'steam' as an adjective (attributive nouns aren't intensifiable by _very_). I have witnesses. So do we say "What a delightful piece of mangling", or do we say " 'steam' has been an adjective since at least 1990"? I believe there has to be a level of usage higher than a few isolated cases.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: That's something different.

Comment: @ermanen Are you saying that it's acceptable to use any string one finds in print or on a notelet say as a word, but only in ways ... er ... _you_? ... find acceptable? If my son used 'steam' as an adjective, why is that less valid than someone using 'farsickness' as a noun?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: tchrist gave a good answer [in this question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/215998/can-one-ever-say-for-certain-a-word-does-not-exist). I agree with him.

Comment: @ermanen That's two of you at least, then. I think it's less autocratic-sounding to subscribe to Janus Bahs Jacquet's statement in that thread: 'Decades of academics studying these thugs in detail have been unable to come up with a definition of _word_ they can agree on, so I think perhaps you're being a bit ambitious in thinking we can do so here.'

Answer (score 6):

Depending on the context, *wanderlust* might work for you:
["strong longing for or impulse toward wandering" (M-W)](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/wanderlust), depending on how much you associate Fernweh with the act of travelling as opposed to the state of being away from home.

Comment: Funny that _wanderlust_ is a German word also and loaned by English. We might loan "fernweh" also, who knows. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wanderlust) says: "In modern German, the use of the word Wanderlust to mean "desire to travel" is less common, having been replaced by Fernweh (lit. "farsickness"), coined as an antonym to Heimweh ("homesickness")."

Comment: @ermanen: FWIW, as a German phrase I'd put "Wanderlust" with "Weltschmerz" in that it's a semantically valid word, but I've never heard it actually used by native speakers. (I'm not a philosopher, though, so my sample might be skewed.)

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes I use the phrase "**a travel itch**" when I stay home too long.

It might be described as

- "the feeling someone gets when they've stayed home for too long, knowing there is a lot to do and see elsewhere.